# I am looking for a word that means to indirectly support someone or aid someone?

Tags: single-word-requests

It sounds like cooperate or support. I think it starts with c

Comment: Can we presume you have checked the synonyms of aid, cooperate and support and its none of those?

Comment: Are you thinking of "covertly aid"?

Comment: Consider the original meaning of _connive_ (as given by Merriam-Webster): "to pretend ignorance of or fail to take action against something one ought to oppose." The other definitions of _connive_ may also be on point, but you'll have to look those up yourself.

Comment: no not covertly aid, not connive either but thank you. Its close though

Comment: Well, you also have _collude_, _conspire_, _collaborate_, and _cabal_, to say nothing of _combine_  and _confederate_. But these begin to sound like the increasingly desperate guesses of an unsuccessful game show contestant.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest "to champion". You can champion someone's beliefs or ideals without directly supporting the person.

Words not starting with 'c'

to back

to endorse

to defend